# The difference between the HCF and LCM of $x$ and $18$ is $120$. Find $x$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving, gcd-and-lcm

> The difference between the HCF and LCM of $x$ and $18$ is $120$. Find $x$.

What I Tried: Let $\gcd(x , 18) = y$ and lcm$(x , 18) = z$ . Also, $z \geq y$ . We have :-
$$\rightarrow 18x = yz$$
And :-
$$\rightarrow z - y = 120$$
$$\rightarrow\frac{18x}{y} - y = 120$$
$$\rightarrow 18x - 120y - 120 = y^2$$
From here, we get that $6 | y^2$ $\rightarrow 6 | y$ .

After doing this, I am stuck. I do get this information but I am not able to use it somehow for $x$ , I could show that $x = 6k$ , but what to do next?

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: $y\le18$ so $y=6,12,18$

Comment: Oh got it, I think I was a bit foolish missing that information as well.

Comment: $\gcd(6k,18)=18$ or $6$, depending whether $3|k$ or not

Comment: $\dfrac{18x}y-y-120\implies 18x-120y=y^2$, not $18x-120y-120=y^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y\le 18,y=6,12,18$. Reject $12$ since it is not a factor of $18$.

We get corresponding $z=120+y=126,138$. Reject $138$ since it is not a multiple of $18$.

We are left with $y=6,z=126,x=yz/18=42$.

Answer (score 3):

**No casework needed.**

$\gcd(x,18) + 120 = \text{lcm} (x,18) \implies \gcd(x,18) \equiv -120 \equiv 6 \pmod{18}$

Therefore $\gcd(x,18)=6, x = \gcd(x,18)\cdot \text{lcm}(x,18)/18 = 6 \cdot 126/18=42$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

as $\text{lcm}(x,18)$ is even :$\gcd(x,18)$ is even .That is $\gcd(x,18)=2$ or $\gcd(x,18)=6$  or $\gcd(x,18)=18$

which do you think will work??

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

WLOG $(x,18)=d>0$  and $\dfrac xp=\dfrac{18}q=d$

$\implies(p,q)=1$ and LCM$(x,18)=pqd$

and $120=pqd-d=d(pq-1)\implies p=\dfrac{\dfrac{120}d+1}q=\dfrac{\dfrac{120}d+1}{\dfrac{18}d}=\dfrac{120+d}{18}$

Clearly, $3|d$ and $2|d\implies d$ must be divisible by LCM$(2,3)=?$

As $d|18$ and $d|120,d$ must divide $(18,120)=6$

So, $d$ has a unique value!

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to note that the HCF has to be a factor of $18$ and there are only $6$ of those to try.  We also know that the product of the HCF and LCM is $18x$ so we can make a table
$$\begin {array} {r r r r}HCF&LCM&18x&x\\ \hline 
1&121&121&NA\\
2&122&244&NA\\
3&123&369&NA\\
6&126&756&42\\
9&129&1161&NA\\
18&138&2484&138\end{array}$$
where the NAs come because $18x$ is odd.  Only $x=42, HCF=6, LCM=126$ works